# Is there a plugin (ideally something that places a button on the toolbar) to switch between different Chrome (or Firefox) profiles?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, multiple-users

Basically I want something like OS X's user switching, but on an app level basic, in this case the app being Chrome or Firefox. Something like this:

#### Personal Profile

- Logged in to my personal gmail account
- Logged in to my personal Twitter account
- Logged in to my personal AdSense and AdWrods
- etc.

#### Work Profile

- Logged in to my Company's gmail account
- Logged in to Yammer, etc.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

(I don't use Chrome, so I'm answering for Firefox only.)

You can launch Firefox with a specific profile using `firefox -p profilename`. Note that this will open a new window with the existing profile if an instance already exists - add `-no-remote` to force it to open a new instance. `-no-remote` also means that it won't respond to things like opening a link from other applications.

There's also an extension for Firefox, [ProfileSwitcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/profileswitcher/), that adds an item to the menu to simplify this process.

There are other, more advanced, extensions that help with profile management:

- [Switchy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/switchy/)
- [MultiFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/)